# Integration of $(x-1)$.

Tags: integration

Which is the correct integrand of $(x-1)$? Is it $\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$ or $\frac{x^2}{2}-x$? They have different values as I have checked. So which one is actually correct?

Comment: Indefinite integrals are only unique up to a + constant

Comment: Hint: Take derivatives of your "results." What do you see?

Comment: @Alan so both are correct in case of Indefinite integrals? I checked that definite integration gives  the same value for both of them.

Comment: @SeanRoberson they are both same. So this means both are correct, right?

Comment: Yes, they are both correct.

Comment: "Up to a constant value" is a phrase worth getting used to in this regard :)

Comment: @Amit "Up to an additive constant" better.

Comment: It gets really fun when you do $\int \sin x \cos x dx$ and end up with either $\frac 1 2 \sin  ^2 x,  -\frac 1 2 \cos ^2 x,  or -\frac 1 4 \cos 2x$, depending on which method you use...all of which are different from each other by an additive constant

Answer (score 2):

Both are partially correct. If you open $\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$ you'll get $\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\frac12$

One can clearly see that $\frac{x^2}{2}-x+1/2$ and $\frac{x^2}{2}-x$ only differ by a constant. And if you'll differentiate both functions you'll get the same result i.e. $x-1$

The correct answer is $\frac{x^2}{2}-x+C$ or $\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\lambda$ where $C$ and $\lambda$ are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1):

Represent $x-1$ as $x+-1$, then integrate $x$ and $-1$ to get $\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $-x$. Add them together to get $\frac{x^2}{2}-x$, which is almost the correct integration. You then need to add the $+C$.

Edit: The other form mentioned is also correct.

Answer (score -2):

as I'm sure you know

$(x-1)= x -1$
so $$\int (x-1)dx = \int x-1 dx$$
on the LHS, substitute $(x-1)=u$

so $$ \int u du = \frac{x^2}{2}-x+C $$
which means
$$\frac {u^2}{2} +C=\frac{x^2}{2}-x+C$$

whcih essentially means
$$\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+C= \frac{x^2}{2} -x+C$$